# Json4s not serializing Java classes

Tags: java, scala, json4s

I have some scala code that needs to be able to serialize/deserialize some Java classes using Json4s.

I am using `"org.json4s" %% "json4s-ext" % "4.0.5"` and `"org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "4.0.5"` though I have also tried with the `3.6.7` version.

Model Code (Java):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Blah {
    @JsonProperty("what")
    public final String what;

    public Blah() {
        this(null);
    }
    public Blah(String what) {
        this.what = what;
    }
}
```

Serialization (Scala):

```
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization

println(Serialization.write(new Blah("helloooo!!!!"))(DefaultFormats))
```

It only ever prints out: `{}`.

I understand I can write a `CustomSerializer` for each Java class but I have a lot of Java classes and would really like to avoid doing that. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: BEWARE: [json4s is vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks!](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)

Comment: BEWARE: @AndriyPlokhotnyuk is constantly promoting his own JSON library.

Comment: Tim, if you are using json4s really then I feel sorry for your clients, who are misled by your decisions. Can it be explanation why you are hidden under some nick here?

Answer (score 3):

Json4s is the Json library for Scala. To work with Java objects, it is recommended to directly use Jackson. See this question [here](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/361)

> Json4s uses jackson only as a parser, and after parsing, it all works by matching from Json4s AST to Scala objects.
>
> If you want to work with Java collections, you should use Jackson
> directly

So, we can get the `mapper` which is an object of Jackson's `ObjectMapper` and use it normally -

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods

println(JsonMethods.mapper.writeValueAsString(new Blah("helloooo!!!!")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add getter method for your `what` property

Comment: I added a `public String getWhat()` method and it still didn't work. Also tried adding `@JsonGetter` annotation to it but I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Json4s ignores any `JsonProperty` annotation and requires both a constructor parameter and a Scala case-class style getter method for each property of your Java model class. In the example above that would look like:

```
public class Blah {
    private final String what;

    public String what() {
        return what;
    }

    public Blah() {
        this(null);
    }
    public Blah(String what) {
        this.what = what;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get a `{}` with that code.

Comment: The above is working for sure... but @SKumar is right. If you are just dealing with Java classes you're better not using Json4s